# why XLC compiler on bluegene/q doesn't support '-qtm'?

Tags: c, xlc, transactional-memory

I have a problem with the xlc compiler on BlueGene/q. The version of the xlc compiler is 12.1:

```
IBM XL C/C++ for Blue Gene, V12.1 Version: 12.01.0000.0000
```

According to the document[1](https://support.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/images/c/cf/Bgqcproguide.pdf), it should support the compiler option "-qtm", which is used to enable the Transactional Memory. However, I always got the following error message:

```
Option -qtm is not valid. Enter xlc_r for list of valid options.
```

How can I figure it out? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the documentation and the compiler executable do not match. What does `xlc_r` reveal about transactional memory?

Answer (score 0):

Are you invoking the compiler as **bgxlc** ?

Comment: I should use bgxlc_r instead of xlc_r. Thank you all the same.